# How can i use just one if statement and include all these conditions in OR (python)

Tags: python, if-statement, or-condition

How can i use just one if statement and include all these conditions along with i++ based on each condition? (using & or etc)??

```
def validator_fn(value):
i=0
if re.search(r'experience',value.casefold()):
    i+=1
if re.search(r'programmer',value.casefold()):
    i+=1
if re.search(r'computer',value.casefold()):
    i+=1
if re.search(r'work',value.casefold()): #skill
    i+=1
if re.search(r'skill',value.casefold()):
    i+=1
if re.search(r'work',value.casefold()):
    i+=1
return i
```

Comment: If multiple patterns match, should `i` be increased multiple times or only once?

Answer (score 3):

Create a loop:

```
def validator_fn(value):
    i = 0
    for s in [r'experience', r'programmer', r'computer', ...]:
        if re.search(s, value.casefold()):
            i += 1
    return i
```

Comment: And you don't really need those `r`s before your strings but I included them just in case you want to modify your regex in future.

Answer (score 2):

Apply all of them at once; `i` is just the number of them that return `True`.

```
def validator_fn(value):
    v = value.casefold()
    search_terms = ['experience', 'programmer', 'computer', 'work', 'skill', 'work']
    return sum(re.search(x, v) is not None for x in search_terms)
```

The sum works because `True == 1` and `False == 0`, `bool` being a subclass of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
if re.search('experience|programmer|computer|work|skill',value.casefold()):
    i+=1
```

You can use `|` ("or") to separate the patterns you want to search for.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but that won't increment i more than once.  For the original code, 'experience,programmer' would increment i twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are just summing 1 for each one that matches, so can do something like:

```
def validator_fn(value):
    v = value.casefold()
    return sum([1 if re.search(pat, v) else 0
               for pat in ['experience', 'programmer', 'computer',
                           'work', 'skill', 'work']])
```